# jquery animate is not animating all content

Tags: jquery

This is my html

```
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service" class="service" id="service-{entry_id}" style="display: none;">
<div id="wrap1">
    <div class="inner">
        <!-- image in here -->
        <h1 itemprop="name">{title}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="wrap2">
    <div class="inner">
        <p itemprop="description">{description}</p>
        <a class="enquire-button" href="mailto:http://www.test.com?subject={title}">enquire about this product</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my js

```
 $('#' + id).animate({
            height: 'toggle'
        },
        duration,
        function() {
        }
    ); // end animate
```

I am not getting the image animating. All of a sudden it just jumps into view. How can I get the whole article including content to animate?

Comment: And what exactly is duration ?

Comment: Ah sorry, duration is defined further up. Its 500

Comment: What is `id`? The `id` of the article element?

Comment: You did set a height in CSS, and then hid the element with the display style, right ?

Comment: Provide the outputted HTML and javascript that the browser sees. And have you closed the article element, i.e. </article>

Comment: Has the image element had time to load before you start the animation? If not it makes sense that it won't animate into view smoothly. Seems to work OK for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/MuHBZ/